NextAuth.js Google authentication stuck in loading state after server restart in Next.js app
I'm developing a Next.js app that utilizes NextAuth.js (^4.24.7) for Google authentication. Everything works fine initially, but I'm encountering an issue where after I close the server in VS Code and then restart it, NextAuth.js gets stuck in a loading state, i have to manually refresh the page to make it work normally.
Here's the scenario:
Start the Next.js server.
Log in with Google using NextAuth.js. Authentication works as expected.
Close the server  in VS Code.
Restart the server.
NextAuth.js remains stuck in a loading state, even though the user is already logged in.
After a long time in loading, it gives this error: Chunk Load Error: Loading chunk app/layout failed.
(timeout: http://localhost:3000/%5C_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js)
Manually refreshing the page shows that the user is logged in and everything works fine.
Based on Chunk Load Error, I deleted the .next folder, cleared the browser cache but it was of no use.
Auth Options:
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(params) {
      try {
        await dbConnection();
        const profile = params.profile as GoogleProfile;
        const userExists = await UserModel.findOne({ email: profile?.email });
        if (!userExists) {
          const email = profile?.email;
          const atIndex = email.indexOf("@");
          const username = email.slice(0, atIndex);
          await UserModel.create({
            email,
            name: profile?.name,
            profilePicture: profile?.picture,
            username,
          });
        }
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }
    },
    async session({ session }) {
      await dbConnection();
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
      session.user._id = user?._id.toString();
      session.user.email = user?.email;
      session.user.profilePicture = user?.profilePicture;
      session.user.username = user?.username;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

Route:
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

LAYOUT:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} flex flex-col min-h-screen`}>
        <Providers>
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="system"
            enableSystem
            disableTransitionOnChange
          >
            <Toaster richColors position="top-center" />
            <Navbar />
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Root Page:
export default function Home() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session) {
      console.log("session is not present");
    } else {
      console.log("session is present");
    }
    console.log("user", session?.user);
  }, [session, status]);
  return (<div>..Static Landing Page..</div>)
}

Provider:
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
export const Providers = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

Navbar:
"use client";
// imports
const Navbar = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "loading" || status === "authenticated") {
      return;
    }
    if (!session) {
      router.push("/");
      return;
    }
  }, [session, status, router]);

  return (
    <div className="sticky top-0 z-10 flex w-full justify-center border-b border-gray-300 bg-gradient-to-b from-zinc-200 backdrop-blur-2xl dark:border-neutral-800 dark:bg-zinc-800/30 dark:from-inherit lg:bg-gray-200 lg:dark:bg-zinc-800/30 py-3">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center container px-1 xs:px-4">
        <div
          onClick={() => router.push("/")}
          className="text-2xl font-bold flex gap-4 hover:cursor-pointer"
        >
          <Image
            src="/Jarno-Single-engine-Cessna.svg"
            alt="Vercel Logo"
            width={100}
            height={24}
            className="-scale-x-100 -rotate-12"
          />
          <p className="hidden sm:flex">Title</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
          <ModeToggle />
          {status === "authenticated" ? (
            <DropdownMenuComponent />
          ) : (
            <Button
              disabled={status === "loading"}
              className="disabled:bg-gray-400"
              onClick={() => signIn()}
            >
              {status === "loading" ? "Processing" : "Login"}
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

Dropdown Menu Component:
export function DropdownMenuComponent() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  let profilePicture = session?.user?.profilePicture;
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "loading") {
      return;
    } else if (status === "authenticated") {
      profilePicture = session?.user?.profilePicture;
      return;
    } else {
      router.push("/");
      return;
    }
  }, [session, status]);

  return (
    <div>drop down content</div>
  );
}

The loading state in Navbar is what keeps on loading. I do not need the session in root page, just added it to check the session.
